# Split String Into 2D Variant Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an example cell with this value as one long string:

```
1;#SCAN035545,2;#SCAN025196,3;#SCAN025192,4;#SCAN020504,5;#SCAN002824,6;#SCAN025354,7;#SCAN037102,8;#SCAN035977,9;#SCAN035763,10;#SCAN032932,11;#SCAN025000,12;#SCAN019935,13;#SCAN039383,14;#SCAN039376,15;#SCAN028043,16;#SCAN999999,17;#SCAN039427,18;#SCAN039419,19;#SCAN039188,20;#SCAN029674,21;#SCAN042707
```

Where ";" and ", are delimiters.

I need to ultimately:
Find a certain term (SCAN999999);

1. Delete it and its accompanying number (16);
2. Renumber all the remaining codes (15;#SCAN028043,16;#SCAN999999,17;#SCAN039427,18;#SCAN039419 -> 15;#SCAN028043,16;#SCAN039427,17;#SCAN039419);
3. Join all the remaining terms back into a string like in the original (1;#SCAN035545,2;#SCAN025196,3;#SCAN025192, etc)

This will then loop through the next cell, etc. I need to do this for a dynamic number of cells and for a dynamic length of string (could go into the hundreds of delimiters). This is just to make it clear that this needs to be fairly dynamic.

What I am stuck on: 1 & 2

I assume the best way to handle the data is to turn the string into an array or table with 2 columns like this:
1 | #SCAN035545
2 | #SCAN025196
3 | #SCAN025192

Is this feasible and which is the way to go? If I use an array, I would need a Variant type, but I'm not sure how to split a string into a Variant array since the split code only works with String arrays.

If I use a table (with a listobject table that I can reset # rows), I worry it might make everything sluggish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Load input strings from column A
- Save result on column B

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrRes(), arrData, arr1, arr2, arr1res()
    Dim rngData As Range, iIndex As Long
    Const KEYWORD = "#SCAN999999" ' search term start with #
    ' Load data into an array from column A (modify as needed)
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ReDim arrRes(1 To UBound(arrData), 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        ' KEYWORD matching
        If InStr(arrData(i, 1), KEYWORD) > 0 Then
            ' Split by ","
            arr1 = Split(arrData(i, 1), ",")
            ReDim arr1res(LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1))
            iIndex = 1
            For j = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
                ' Split by ","
                arr2 = Split(arr1(j), ";")
                If UCase(arr2(1)) = KEYWORD Then
                    arr1(j) = "" ' Skip matching term
                Else
                    arr2(0) = CStr(iIndex)
                    arr1res(iIndex - 1) = Join(arr2, ";")
                    iIndex = iIndex + 1
                End If
            Next j
            ReDim Preserve arr1res(LBound(arr1) To iIndex - 2)
            arrRes(i, 1) = Join(arr1res, ",")
        Else
            arrRes(i, 1) = arrData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Update cells on column B
    rngData.Offset(0, 1).Value = arrRes
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been making overly complicated code for over two days and this looks so nice and concise. This is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
=LET(
    input,
    INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,";",","),,2),
    middle,
    FILTER(input,input<>"#SCAN999999"),
    output,
    MAKEARRAY(ROWS(middle),2,LAMBDA(_r,_c,IF(_c=1,_r,INDEX(middle,_r,1)))),
    TEXTJOIN(",",,BYROW(output,LAMBDA(_r,TEXTJOIN(";",,_r))))
)
```

Input:

> 1;#SCAN035545,2;#SCAN025196,3;#SCAN025192,4;#SCAN020504,5;#SCAN002824,6;#SCAN025354,7;#SCAN037102,8;#SCAN035977,9;#SCAN035763,10;#SCAN032932,11;#SCAN025000,12;#SCAN019935,13;#SCAN039383,14;#SCAN039376,15;#SCAN028043,16;#SCAN999999,17;#SCAN039427,18;#SCAN039419,19;#SCAN039188,20;#SCAN029674,21;#SCAN042707

Output:

> 1;#SCAN035545,2;#SCAN025196,3;#SCAN025192,4;#SCAN020504,5;#SCAN002824,6;#SCAN025354,7;#SCAN037102,8;#SCAN035977,9;#SCAN035763,10;#SCAN032932,11;#SCAN025000,12;#SCAN019935,13;#SCAN039383,14;#SCAN039376,15;#SCAN028043,16;#SCAN039427,17;#SCAN039419,18;#SCAN039188,19;#SCAN029674,20;#SCAN042707